# In "Bugger Indian passport", is bugger an adjective of "passport" or of "India"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

One of my friends said this. I have been pretty sure bugger is an adjective of the "passport". But, I was surprised that some of my friends interpreted as an adjective of "India". And some nationalistic pride was hurt. How do I convince them that there is no such issue?

The context was something like this:

To go to the UK, do you guys from USA need a visa?
Yes, I do. Bugger Indian passport.

Comment: Could you please give us the context in which "Bugger Indian passport" is used.

Comment: If it needs a context, it is not unequivocal as I think it is.

Comment: It needs a context.

Comment: Perhaps instead of asking 'How do I convince them that there is no such issue?' you should consider 'how do I apologize to my friends'. Nothing about the phrase inherently makes 'bugger' modify 'passport' instead of 'Indian', so all you are left with is your intent.

Comment: You are assuming I said this phrase, which I did not say anywhere. One of the friends did. Anyway, my English is not as good as I thought it is. I thought there is only one interpretation.

Comment: @JakeRegier, added the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained, Bugger is a verb. Your question will be valid with any sentence like `bad indian passport`.
 In this example, bad will not be adjective of 'indian' or 'passport' but for whole 'indian passport' as this whole term is a noun here, not individual words.

Answer (score 1):

As quoted, and lacking additional context, I take it for a verb (meaning 'sodomize' or sim, q.v.) not an adjective. In either case it would seem to indicate contempt, whether for India, passports, or Indian passports.

Comment: I added the context.

Answer (score 1):

Salil, thank you for the context.  Here's the conversation, I would have expected:

> Indian: Do you Americans need a visa to go to the UK?
>   American: No, just a passport.  How about you?
>   Indian: My passport isn't good enough. I have to get a standard visitors visa as well.  Bugger the Indian passport.

"Bugger" is slang for committing anal sodomy and has long been used as a term of contempt, evolving to an expression of moderate exasperation with something.  As a verb, it doesn't modify anything.  It's direct object is "passport," which "Indian" modifies.

The exasperation seems misplaced, though.  The target should be the governments of the two countries, not the harmless passport.  After all, if you're an Afghan, the UK will require a visa to visit.  And India requires a visa of Britons (and indeed, of all foreign nationals) who want to visit India.

Comment: Ok, thanks. As an added context, this was a group of friends talking with each other. So, political correctness was not the top priority.